# Send data from activity to different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` in which I have a spinner which have three items. Those items are used to inflate three different fragments in `MainActivity framelayout`.

Now I've another `FilterActivity` which I get by clicking on `menuItem` in `MainActivity`. So my `FilterActivity` is attached with `MainActivity`.

In `FilterActivity` I've three radio buttons. When I check any of the radio button and click on OK button, it get me to the `MainActivity`.

What I want is to get the value from `FilterActivity` to my all three fragments. As if I check any radio button in `FilterActivty`, its related data should be available in all three fragments.

I've tried to do it with Bundle but its not working.

In my `FilterActivity`, and `ReportType` is my fragment where I want to send this data.

```
else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_check_filter)
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Expense", EXPENSE_TYPE);
            ReportType reportType = new ReportType();
            reportType.setArguments(bundle);

            finish();
        }
```

And in the same fragment, I tried to get that value by doing this.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String expenseType1 = bundle.getString("Expense");
```

But this gives me NullPointerException, which mean the bundle have no value.

Here is my FilterActivity

```
    public class Filter extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private LinearLayout allTypeWrapper, incomeTypeWrapper, expenseTypeWrapper;
    private ImageView imgAllType, imgIncome, imgExpense;

    private String EXPENSE_TYPE;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    //Expense Type wrappers
        allTypeWrapper = findViewById(R.id.all_type_wrapper);
        incomeTypeWrapper = findViewById(R.id.income_type_wrapper);
        expenseTypeWrapper = findViewById(R.id.expense_type_wrapper);

        allTypeWrapper.setOnClickListener(this);
        incomeTypeWrapper.setOnClickListener(this);
        expenseTypeWrapper.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Expense type images
        imgAllType = findViewById(R.id.img_all_type);
        imgIncome = findViewById(R.id.img_income);
        imgExpense = findViewById(R.id.img_expense);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Filter");
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_check_reset, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_restore_filter)
        {

        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_check_filter)
        {
            Intent intent  = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Expense", EXPENSE_TYPE);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        //Expense type
        if (id == R.id.all_type_wrapper)
        {
            EXPENSE_TYPE = "ALL";
            imgAllType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_checked);
            imgIncome.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_unchecked);
            imgExpense.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_unchecked);
        }

        else if (id == R.id.income_type_wrapper)
        {
            EXPENSE_TYPE = "INCOME";
            imgAllType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_unchecked);
            imgIncome.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_checked);
            imgExpense.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_unchecked);
        }

        else if (id == R.id.expense_type_wrapper)
        {
            EXPENSE_TYPE = "EXPENSE";
            imgAllType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_unchecked);
            imgIncome.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_unchecked);
            imgExpense.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rb_checked);
        }
    }
}
```

I want someone to explain me how can I get a value from an Activity and pass it to different fragments.

Comment: Welcome to SO, `` this symbols are not meant to be highlight your text, it always meant to put some code snippets inside only.

Comment: ok I'll keep it in mind next time...Thanx for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you press on the `OK` button on your `FilterActivity` it gets you to the `MainActivity`.

You can call your `FilterActivity` using `startActivityForResult` and pass your data to `main activity` using `setResult`.

call your `FilterActivity` from `MainActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FilterActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In `FilterActivity` pass data to main activity

```
else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_check_filter){

   Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
   returnIntent.putExtra("Expense",EXPENSE_TYPE);
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
   finish();
}
```

In your `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String result = "initial value";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

      if (requestCode == 1) {
          if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
              result = data.getStringExtra("Expense");
          }
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
              //Write your code if there's no result
          }
      }
   }
   // to access your data from fragements
    public String getMyData() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

From your `fragment` you can access your value like

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        String dataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
        Log.d("TAG", "Your data from activity "+dataFromActivity);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your `FilterActivity` you can check is `EXPENSE_TYPE` set or not

```
 else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btn_check_filter){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EXPENSE_TYPE)){
       // show toast or log that you have to select an expense type
       return false;
    }
    // EXPENSE_TYPE is not null or empty
    Intent intent  = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Expense", EXPENSE_TYPE);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: it gives me null value.

Comment: yes it gives me null value at `onActivityResult`. I ran debugger and put break point at  `intent.putExtra("Expense", EXPENSE_TYPE);` here. `EXPENSE_TYPE` is a string variable and its have String value in it but when I ran debugger here `intent.putExtra("Expense", EXPENSE_TYPE);` its take me to the runTimeException

`public Intent putExtra(String name, @RecentlyNullable String value) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }` here

Comment: yes I updated my question...check FilterActivity full code

Comment: I still have same problem

Comment: still same problem... Here `Report report = new Report();
        String type = report.getMyData();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+type, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`this Toast popup and show null written in it...Report is my Activity

Comment: Oh no. you should not create new instance of your "Report" class. btw is `Report` class an activity where `fragment` is loaded?

Comment: Then you have to  do like that `Report  report = (Report) getActivity();`  `String type = report.getMyData();`

Comment: Thanx it worked for... Thanx again for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You said the Fragments you are using are hosted on you **MainActivity**, that means you already created those fragment instances with your **MainActivty**. But you are tring to create a new instance and set arguments on **FitlerActivity** which is not the Host of the Fragments. In the way you are approaching its not gonna work.

You can try getting the **EXPENSE_TYPE** from your **FilterActivity** to Your **MainActivity**, then recreating the fragments in the **MainActivity** with **EXPENSE_TYPE** in their arguments.

Comment: That sound some logical to me...Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using setArguements in Android

```
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And retrieve them using

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

**Use Add Fragment Method.**

Comment: That's what I've tried but its not working in this case.

Comment: You need to delay transaction, because when you hit radio button the fragment is already been created

Answer (score 0):

In your `FilterActivity` onRadio button click listener add following code:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra( "key1", values);// add values to intent you want to send to MainActivity.
    intent.putExtra( "key2", values);
    setResult(2,intent);
    finish();
```

In your `MainActivity` add following code to start `FilterActivity` :

```
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId( );
        if (id == R.id.your_Id) 
            Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext( ),FilterActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult( intent, 2);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
    }
```

Here `startActivityForResult` will bring back the data from `FilterActivity` after selecting the radio options. Add this function to your `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            String yourValues = data.getIntExtra( "key1", 0 );
        //create the bundle here to send data to the fragment
        }
    }
```

Now add `yourValues` to the bundle (hope you can do it yourself) and then send these bundle to your fragment.
And let me know if it is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

There is so many ways to send Data from you Activity to diffarent fragments present in the same Activity

Method 1:- Use EventBus such as [Otto Event Bus](https://square.github.io/otto/) or [GreenRobert](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

in my case GreenRobert is vary easy to learn and implement

Method 2:- Use BroadcastReceiver which is simple to learn

Method 3:- Use Bundle to send Data to your fragments

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this

1. Get the type from filtered activity to main activity, then on loading the fragment in main activity send it via ARG (bundle that you are using).
2. Second option is a hack, where you can skip these steps. 
   In filtered activity save a string value to shared pref according to Expense type
   And then use it anywhere in fragment.

Goodluck